# Problem with theme registry rebuild and drupal_get_form in a block

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, caching, theming

I'm calling a form from a custom block and having real problems getting it to function with theme registry rebuild on each page load turned off.

With the registry rebuilding every page load this form is called and functions fine within the block, however once rebuild is off drupal_get_form() doesn't appear to call the form at all, I've place debugging within the form function to confirm this.

I'm completely stumped as to why this would be, I've tried wrapping drupal_get_form in a drupal_render, same problem, the form just doesn't get called once registry rebuild is off. The form is also called in hook_menu and the block was created so I could place it in some panels within other pages. I can see no reason why this would interfere  with calling the form from a block.

I've pasted some abstracted code below to see if anyone can see an obvious issue that I'm missing, it really is infuriating. As it stands at the moment I've resorted to using a custom pane with PHP to call the module file and invoke drupal_get_form from there, this works fine with the registry rebuild off, so it seems it must have something to do with the block.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info()
 */
function example_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['example_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Hello world'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    'status' => TRUE,
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view()
 */
function example_block_view($delta = 'example_form') {
  global $user;
  if (isset($user) && $user->uid != 0 && !empty($user->mail)){
    $example_form = drupal_get_form('example_page_form', $user, 'arg');
    $block['subject'] = t('Example block form');
    $block['content'] = $example_form;
    return $block;
  }
}
```

The form I'm calling also requires two arguments that I am passing to it, I don't see why this would cause an issue however.

Comment: I see weird things happening with forms in blocks sometimes, I usually get around it by forcing the form to render there and then, i.e. `$block['content'] = drupal_render($example_form);`

Comment: Did you set other option than `DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` at first?